# PHP create file out of POST, then force user to download it - not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a page with some forms and input fields, which the user fills in and then they are sent to a php page via Ajax and $_POST.
And then the php File writes the output to a txt file. - that works just fine. My problem is I am trying to force the user to download it on that same page that creates the file, after the file is created and I can't seem to get it to work, nothing happens besides the file being created:

Here the code where the .txt File is created (this works nice):

```
$myfile = fopen("test.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

foreach ($URLsArray as &$url) {
     $row=$SomeArray[$keys[$index]]."\t".$SomeArray[$keys[$index]]."\t".$SomeArray[$keys[$index]]."\t".$SomeArray[$keys[$index]]."\t".$url."\n";
     fwrite($myfile, $zeile);
     $index = $index  + 1;
}
fclose($myfile);
```

And here the code, where I try to force the download: (after the fclose)

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename('test.txt'));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('test.txt'));
readfile('test.txt');
exit;
```

And when I try this I get the error: "Unexpected token A". "A" is the first letter in the test.txt, which is created.

And I know that there are a lot of similar questions, but not one solution worked for me.

I hope someone can help me :)

Comment: AJAX means a _background_ request, you can not directly trigger a download dialog from there by server response. Most simple solution: _Don’t_ use AJAX, but submit a normal form instead.

Comment: you can download the ajax response, which is not done with php settings, but rather with client-side JS. you can use my download library as an ajax callback: https://github.com/rndme/download

Comment: @CBroe: Thanks for your comment :) But i need Ajax, because the data I POST to the PHP file are arrays, which I create out of the inputs the user gave. Or can I send arrays with a normal form?

Comment: @dandavis: okay that looks interesting, so all I would have to do is to get the filename of the created txt file, via the ajax success method and then call your download method with the returned filename?

Comment: The first piece of code doesn't look complete. Can you post a complete example? It might be possible that you're echoing something before the headers that would create an invalid HTTP response.

Comment: yeah, if it's text, you can keep it in a string an download(theString,"myfile.txt") anytime/anywhere. if it's a bin file, you need to get a blob responseType, and pluck the filename from a header or something, then feed the blob and name back to download().

Comment: @axblount nope there are no echos before the headers, this is just after the fclose

Comment: Since this is probably gonna be a rather small amount of data, you probably don’t “need” either AJAX or PHP – but instead you could simply assemble the data in the desired format client-side, and then create a _Data URI_ out of it and assign it to `location.href` to trigger a download …

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this backend with PHP you could try to do this on the frontend part. The easiest solution is to write some JavaScript code which adds an iframe to your webpage. The iframe should then have a href to the file you want the user to download.

Answer (score 0):

**Okay here my solution**: @CBroe thanks for the hint with the *background* request, I would have tried for ages to get the download work in the php file. So what I did:

In PHP: I echo the filename after the .txt file is created:

```
echo json_encode(array('filename' => "your_Data".time().".txt"));
```

Than in JavaScript I read the filename in the success method and put the link in an `<a>` element. Later that will be a button which is set active.

```
success : function(data) {
        $("#button_get_file_download").attr("href", "urlToFolder"+data.filename);
},
```